# Removing Decimal Point From a Query Output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query, but need it to return whole numbers instead of a decimal fraction.

How might i change the query to do this?

```
RIGHT(' '+REPLACE(AP.APRLOS, '.',''),3) AS TOT_AUTH_LEN_STAY,
```

Comment: `SELECT FLOOR(yourcol)`

Comment: Give some example values and desired results.

Comment: examples  are 3.5, 8.7 and desired results are 35, 87 etc

Comment: ...and type of AP.APRLOS and type of desired output TOT_AUTH_LEN_STAY?

Comment: @MartinSmith As an 87 apparently

Comment: So are you always just multiplying by 10? Do all of the values stored have exactly one decimal place? If not give some examples of those too.

Comment: SELECT REPLACE(1.23, '.', '') will work. But if looking at the examples it looks like multiplying by 10 will work I guess.

Answer (score -2):

For that portion of your query, use

```
Floor(AP.APRLOS,1)
```

Comment: What's the second parameter of `1` for? `Floor` only takes one param. This doesn't help converting `8.7` to `87` anyway though.

Comment: Reference the following .. the second parameter is "significance' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634815.aspx